# Latex multirow table text and borders messed up

Tags: multirow, booktabs

I have the following table (code below):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[width=.9\linewidth,cols=6,pos=h]
\caption{Description of nodes in the Dynamic Bayesian Network shown in Fig \ref{FIG:dbn}}\label{tab:dbntable}
\begin{tabular*}{\tblwidth}{@{} |l|l|p{0.05\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|@{} }
\toprule
Node name &
  Type &
  Time-steps &
  Conditional   dependcy &
  States &
  Description \\ \midrule
Prior &
  \multirow{6}{*}{Initial} &
  \multirow{6}{*}{t=0} &
  None &
  11 states indicating   score in the range {[}0-10{]} &
  A state of 0 denotes   a student who scored a 0 in the pre-test while a state of 10 represents a   student who scored 100\% in the pre-test \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){4-6} 
Knowledge0 &
   &
   &
  Prior &
  \multirow{10}{*}{True and False} &
  State of true denotes   the possibility that the student has the required knowledge at timestep t=0 \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){6-6} 
Distractor00 &
   &
   &
  \multirow{5}{*}{Knowledge0} &
   &
  \multirow{3}{*}{True denotes the evidence   that the student has collected this distractor at timestep t=0} \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1}
Distractor01 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1}
Distractor02 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){6-6} 
Question0 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  True denotes the   evidence that the student answered the quiz correctly at timestep t=0 \\ \cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){6-6} 
Knowledge1 &
  \multirow{5}{*}{Temporal} &
  \multirow{5}{*}{t=1,2,3} &
   &
   &
  True denotes the   possibility that the student has the required knowledge at timestep t=1,2,3 \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){6-6} 
Distractor10 &
   &
   &
  \multirow{4}{*}{Knowledge1} &
   &
  \multirow{3}{*}{True denotes the evidence   that the student has collected this distractor at timestep t=1,2,3} \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1}
Distractor11 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1}
Distractor12 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){6-6} 
Question1 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  True denotes the   evidence that the student answered the quiz correctly at timestep t=1,2,3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

The table is appearing messed up with weird borders and text going out of page. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: I was able to fix the overflow. but how do I fix the table borders? I want them to be complete instead of broken lines.

Comment: Vertical lines and rules defined in the `booktabs` packages doesn't work well together. You need to replace rules with ˙\hline` or ˙\Xhline` defined in the `makecell` package or with `\hlineB` defined in the `boldline package.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm mentioned in comment, rules from `booktabs` package and vertical lines doesn't gives nice result due to added some vertical space around rules and shortened them if you require (as you did in your table) with `(l)`, `(r)` or `(lr)` options for `\cmidrule`.

See, if the solution used the `makacell` package (for `\Xhline` and additional vertical spaces in cells), `tabularx` (for correct span table width) amd `\multirow{...}{=}{...}` syntax gets what you like to have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[width=\linewidth,cols=6,pos=h]
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells    
\caption{Description of nodes in the Dynamic Bayesian Network shown in Fig \ref{FIG:dbn}}\label{tab:dbntable}
\begin{tabularx}{\tblwidth}{|L|L|
                            >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L|
                            L|
                            >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L|
                            p{0.35\textwidth}|
                            }
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
Node name &
  Type &
  Time-steps &
  Conditional   dependcy &
  States &
  Description \\ 
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
Prior &
  \multirow{6}{=}{Initial} &
  \multirow{6}{=}{t=0} &
  None &
  11 states indicating   score in the range {[}0-10{]} &
  A state of 0 denotes   a student who scored a 0 in the pre-test while a state of 10 represents a   student who scored 100\% in the pre-test \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{4-6}
Knowledge0 &
   &
   &
  Prior &
  \multirow{10}{=}{True and False} &
  State of true denotes   the possibility that the student has the required knowledge at timestep t=0 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6}
Distractor00 &
   &
   &
  \multirow{5}{=}{Knowledge0} &
   &
  \multirow{3}{=}{True denotes the evidence   that the student has collected this distractor at timestep t=0} \\ \cline{1-1}
Distractor01 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\ \cline{1-1}
Distractor02 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{6-6}
Question0 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  True denotes the   evidence that the student answered the quiz correctly at timestep t=0 \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{6-6}
Knowledge1 &
  \multirow{5}{=}{Temporal} &
  \multirow{5}{=}{t=1,2,3} &
   &
   &
  True denotes the   possibility that the student has the required knowledge at timestep t=1,2,3 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6}
Distractor10 &
   &
   &
  \multirow{4}{=}{Knowledge1} &
   &
  \multirow{3}{=}{True denotes the evidence   that the student has collected this distractor at timestep t=1,2,3} \\ \cline{1-1}
Distractor11 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\ \cline{1-1}
Distractor12 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{6-6}
Question1 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  True denotes the   evidence that the student answered the quiz correctly at timestep t=1,2,3 \\
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show page layout)